# Keyboard shortcut to auto spacing

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, spacing

Is there a way on Android Studio to make this:

```
for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
    //something..
}
```

be converted into this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    //something..
}
```

by a keyboard shortcut or something (manually)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reformat the code using the following shortcuts.

**Windows:**  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

**Mac:**  <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

**Note:** All the shortcuts can be found in `settings`, under `keymap`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Android studio` on Windows / Linux use : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

if you are using it on MAC OS use <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, could you please tell me whats the name of that shortcut? I have downloaded skin that might changed that key shortcut.

Comment: Nevermind I found it on the list here:
https://resources.jetbrains.com/assets/products/intellij-idea/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

its called Reformat-Code

Comment: True. I missed it apparently :)